# MongoDB async IIdGenerator for InsertOneAsync operation

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver, kestrel

We have exposed a JobService (which is Dotnet Core service using kestrel) which does MongoDB updates for our object(JobDocument) and are seeing that in case of Post call to createJob which actually triggers MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOneAsync there is a performance hit ie. around 200 concurrent requests make the service unresponsive. After debugging and using some tools, found that issue is in the api call InsertOneAsync. This is using our custom implementation for GenerateId, which uses sync function call FindOneAndUpdate.Is there an async way to GenerateId. How to accomplish this? For reference attaching the stack using tool Ben Blocking detector which points to same:

```
{"Timestamp":"2021-04-03T15:22:38.5854816+05:30","Level":"Warning","MessageTemplate":"Blocking method has been invoked and blocked, this can lead to threadpool starvation.\r\n{stackTrace}","Properties":{"stackTrace":"   

at System.Threading.Tasks.TplEventSource.TaskWaitBegin(Int32 OriginatingTaskSchedulerID, Int32 OriginatingTaskID, Int32 TaskID, TaskWaitBehavior Behavior, Int32 ContinueWithTaskID)\r\n   
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWaitCore(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.PooledConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ServerChannelSource.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ChannelSourceHandle.GetChannel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Create(IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteOperationExecutor.Execute[TResult](IRetryableWriteOperation`1 operation, IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindOneAndUpdate[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass53_0`1.<FindOneAndUpdate>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindOneAndUpdate[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at JobManager.Data.MongoDB.IdGenerator.JobIdGenerator.GenerateId(Object container, Object document)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.AssignId(TDocument document)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ConvertWriteModelToWriteRequest(WriteModel`1 model, Int32 index)\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation..ctor(CollectionNamespace collectionNamespace, IEnumerable`1 requests, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateBulkWriteOperation(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<BulkWriteAsync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<InsertOneAsync>b__0(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOneAsync(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOneAsync(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)\r\n   
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertOneAsync(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Data.MongoDB.Repositories.MongoJobRepository.Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Data.Contract.IJobRepository.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Data.MongoDB.Repositories.MongoJobRepository.Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Data.Contract.IJobRepository.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Services.JobService.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Services.JobService.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Services.JobService.Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Contract.Interfaces.IJobService.CreateJobWithWorkflow(Job job)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Services.JobService.Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Contract.Interfaces.IJobService.CreateJobWithWorkflow(Job job)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Api.Controllers.v2.JobsController.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Api.Controllers.v2.JobsController.CreateJob(Job job)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAwaitedAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAwaitedAsync()\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.Common.Utils.Filters.ContextFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.Common.Utils.Filters.ContextFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAwaitedAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ControllerActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)\r\n  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateRequestDelegate>b__0(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<UseMiddleware>b__2(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at CorrelationId.CorrelationIdMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorrelationContextFactory correlationContextFactory)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at CorrelationId.CorrelationIdMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorrelationContextFactory correlationContextFactory)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<UseMiddleware>b__2(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.Common.Utils.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Code.DataProtection.Common.Utils.ExceptionHandler.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Ben.Diagnostics.BlockingDetectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Ben.Diagnostics.BlockingDetectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiVersioningMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Context context)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 httpApplication)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 httpApplication)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnectionMiddleware`1.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext connectionContext)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection.ExecuteAsync()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection.ExecuteAsync()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()\r\n   
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()\r\n   
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()\r\n","EventId":{"Id":6,"Name":"BlockingMethodCalled"},"SourceContext":"Ben.Diagnostics.BlockingMonitor","ActionId":"25c60a2a-f366-415b-8f16-66e10f134608","ActionName":"Code.DataProtection.JobManager.Api.Controllers.v2.JobsController.CreateJob (JobManager.Api)","RequestId":"0HM7MGOIK401C:00000001","RequestPath":"/api/jobmanager/v2.0/jobs","SpanId":"|11136163-4c80e7d34af376d0.","TraceId":"11136163-4c80e7d34af376d0","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HM7MGOIK401C"}}
```

Comment: is your custom id generation code doing sequential id generation using `FindOneAndUpdate` to increment a counter document in the db? if not, would help to see that code.

Comment: Yes we are using FindOneAndUpdate to increment the counter. We cant use FindOneAndUpdateAsync as it requires the GenerateId api to be async as well but it isnt supported.

Comment: `public class JobIdGenerator : IIdGenerator{
   public object GenerateId(object container, object doc)     {
       IMongoCollection<SequenceDocument> idSeqColl = (IMongoCollection<JobDocument>)container).Database.GetCollection<SequenceDocument>("Sequence");
       var filter = Builders<SequenceDocument>.Filter.Empty;
       var update = Builders<SequenceDocument>.Update.Inc(a => a.Value, 1);
       return idSeqColl.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<SequenceDocument, SequenceDocument>
           {ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, IsUpsert = true}).Value;`

Answer (score 1):

i believe your performance issue stems from the technique used for generating incremental ids using mongodb server and not due to not being able to use `async/await`.

this is a well known scaling/performance limitation of sequential id generation due to mongodb having to lock the counter document in order to increment the value.

for ex: say a single `FindOneAndUpdate` operation takes 50ms to update the counter. now to do that from 200 threads simultaneously would take roughly 200 x 50ms = 10secs or more. i.e. only 1 thread/operation is allowed to write to the counter document at any given time and an exclusive lock is obtained per opertation/thread.

you have a few options here:

- give up using incremental ids and use `ObjectId` instead
- create a background service that pre-generates batches of sequential ids if the current stock is running low. then your `JobIdGenerator` will 'FindOneAndUpdate' the next unused id as `IsUsed:true` instead of trying to increment a single counter doc.

also since there's no `IIdGenerator.GenerateIdAsync` method, you might wanna take things in to your own hands and set the values from you repositories/whatever instead of using `IIdGenerator` when saving/creating new entities.

Comment: Would like to understand why 200 concurrent requests make the service unresponsive such that other api calls become unresponsive? Is it because of threadpool starvation and way Kestrel handles threadpool. Or is there a way such that Kestrel configures threadpool for each endpoint, such that other non-mongo db endpoints continue to work and dont become responsive?

Comment: @nikhilambastha mongodb driver is doing faux sync (sync-over-async anti-pattern) under the hood in order to maintain backward compatibility. `FindOneAndUpdate` is one culprit that locks threads for longer than needed. there may be other places in your service that also uses the legacy sync-over-async api that contributes to the issue. you gotta async/await all the way from top to bottom for io bound work. so don't use `IIdGenerator.GenerateId` and create your own method/service that spits out incremental Ids in a async manner. grab the next incremental id from that service and set on entities.

Comment: Endpoint (url/create)-queries/update mongodb is using FindOneAndUpdate and is blocking.Hence when I have multiple calls for this API, next api to this endpoint becomes unresposive. During this processing time, suppose I call another endpoint say endpoint (/ping) in same service which just returns true/false, it is also becoming unresponsive. Why is that happening? Is it because of the way threadpool is used internally by Kestrel? Do we by any config change make it to use seperate threadpool for diff endpoint,such that my ping responds fine even if my create api is unresponsive.

Comment: please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493). it will help you understand thread pool starvation due to blocking code.